# Точные расчеты действительных чисел для моего генератора частоты

Tags: python-3.x

Мне нужна помощь с точностью расчета, я только учусь и не могу понять ошибку
У меня есть этот скрипт, он выводит этот список чисел после запуска.

```
nums = [108, 109, 110, 111]
for div in nums:
    x = 542357098500868790
    y = 0
    while x > y:
        print(x)
        x = x // div
result
542357098500868790
5021824986119155
46498379501103
430540550936
3986486582
36911912
341776
3164
29

542357098500868790
4975753197255676
45649111901428
418799191756
3842194419
35249490
323389
2966
27
.......
```

Но когда я меняю делитель с '//' на '/'

```
542357098500868790
4.8949196615601875e+17
4.417797528483923e+17
```

Мне нужно, чтобы результат был максимально точным с остатком

```
nums = [1.108, 2.109, 3.110, 4.111]
for div in nums:
    x = 542357098500868790
    y = 0
    while x > y:
        print(x)
        x = x / div
```

I need this result

```
542357098500868790/1.108 = 489491966156018763.53
```

Comment: Точность и количество цифр которые видно- не одно и тоже, остаток и дробная часть, тоже разные вещи, что нужно получить, какая цель преследуется?

Comment: а вот если использовать decimal, результат другой `Decimal(542357098500868790) / Decimal(1.108) = 489491966156018721.1609479212`

Comment: Кстати вот статья *https://habr.com/ru/post/331814/ *прекрасно иллюстрирующая, смысл значащих цифр. Из документации python: Integers have unlimited precision. Floating point numbers are usually implemented using double in C; *https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex*

Comment: Decimal(542357098500868790) / Decimal(1.108) = 489491966156018721.1609479212 Вот это то что мне нужно но как это подкрутить в цыкл

Comment: вы разобрались?

Comment: Нет мне все еще нужна помощь